# Apache + socketIO failing

Tags: php, node.js, apache, socket.io

I have made a chat with `SocketIO` who is working well on local, but i'm trying to deploy it on my `Apache` server.

I'm using Php + NodeJs, not only Node

I had `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error but solved it by opening the good port, `Listen 8000` in my `ports.conf`

My `server.js` look like this

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8000);
// Socket IO usage
```

My `client.js` is

```
var socket = io.connect('http://[MY SERVER IP]:8000');
// Other client code
```

I use `localhost` in local but I changed by my server ip.

But I still have this error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://[MY_SERVER_IP]:8000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1455101301883-60. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'MY DOMAIN' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

I really don't know what to do, this is the first I try to deploy a Nodejs + php app.
I had read some Stackoverflow questions to try to fix it, but i really don't know how...

I don't knwo if this is due to my `Apache` conf or I must change some `NodeJS` or `SocketIO` conf

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

Do not open the NodeJS server port on Apache config. It will make some conflicts and will prevent your Node server to work.

Just change the `localhost` by your server IP and it will work fine.